# Google Authorization in R & PyCharm

Tags: r, google-sheets, pycharm, rtools

Since Google does not support third-party authorization anymore, I wonder how can I access google drive documents. Can I force R to open the pop-up windows not in the viewer but in a browser?

I am using R4.3.0. and PyCharm as IDE.

Thank you!

[image: PyCharm Google Auth]